# Is it possible to programatically convert a Cell Range in Excel to HTML

Tags: c#, html, excel

I don't mind using any external libraries in order to achieve this. I need to get the HTML representation of a Cell Range in Excel (including all formatting such as borders, font style, etc) inside my C# application. We're trying to automate a process where the user copies certain ranges from some excel files to another system.

I've tried using NPOI, COM Interop, OpenXML, and it seems there are no built-in ways to export just a smaller part of a workbook to HTML. NPOI does have a converter for old formats though, but it converts the entire file. And I could use a XLST transformation to convert the OpenXML representation to HTML. But it would take a lot of time which I don't exactly have right now.

Am I missing something? How does Excel itself save its files to HTML format? Can I use this to my advantage somehow? Are there any libraries out there able to do this?

I've done a lot of research but found nothing.

Comment: Have you tried copying the range to a new worksheet and saving that as HTML?

Comment: If Excel will be open while this is occuring, you can use the Clipboard for this.